# Linux, How to sort the lines of a file

Tags: linux, file, sorting

I have a file called `abc`. The content of abc is:

```
ccc
abc
ccc
ccc
a
b
dd
ccc
```

I want to sort the lines of the file and delete all duplicates (in this case ccc are duplicates).

In the shell script I use this:

```
sort -u < $1
```

But the sorted result becomes the standard output instead of saved into the abc file.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect output to a file as

```
sort -u < $1 > abc
```

Comment: In that case, you have to create temporary sorted file and rename it to `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sort -u abc -o abc_sorted
```

or if you want to replace the file

```
sort -u abc -o abc
```

you could also do

```
sort abc | uniq > abc_sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by using the commands `sort` `uniq` , `|` (pipes) and `>` (re direction). If your file name is `file` you can do it simply by the following command:-

```
sort file | uniq >file
```